# What does `Any` in Elixir `defprotocol` actually contains?

Tags: elixir

My *blank.ex* is :

```
defprotocol Blank do
  @fallback_to_any true
  def blank?(data)
end

defimpl Blank, for: Any do
  def blank?(_), do: false
end
```

and I type in iex, the output is:

```
iex(18)> Blank.blank? []
true
iex(19)> Blank.blank? [6]
false
iex(20)> Blank.blank? '12'
false
iex(22)> Blank.blank? "' "
true
iex(23)> Blank.blank? "elixi"
true
iex(24)> Blank.blank? {1}
true
iex(25)> Blank.blank? {1, 2}
true
iex(26)> Blank.blank? 2
false
```

So I'm wondering what does the `Any` means in this context? and I got something interesting, weather or not I use the implemented like this

```
defimpl Blank, for: Any do
  def blank?(_), do: false
end
```

and the output in the iex before it's the same. Does that means this implemented does nothing? Or I have missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` clause should be called if an implementation is not provided.

I don't know why you're getting these weird results, but I suspect you have some incorrect definitions in the shell session. I have tried with the [example from the site](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/4.html):

```
defprotocol Blank do
  @fallback_to_any true
  def blank?(data)
end

defimpl Blank, for: Integer do
  def blank?(_), do: false
end

# Just empty list is blank
defimpl Blank, for: List do
  def blank?([]), do: true
  def blank?(_),  do: false
end

# Just the atoms false and nil are blank
defimpl Blank, for: Atom do
  def blank?(false), do: true
  def blank?(nil),   do: true
  def blank?(_),     do: false
end

defimpl Blank, for: Any do
  def blank?(_), do: false
end
```

And got expected results:

```
iex(1)> Blank.blank? "' "
false

iex(2)> Blank.blank? "elixi"
false

iex(3)> Blank.blank? []
true

iex(4)> Blank.blank? {}  # fallback to Any
false
```

The last example is a fallback to `Any`, since the protocol is not defined for a tuple. If you remove the `Any` implementation, and **restart** the shell, you should get an error:

```
iex(1)> Blank.blank? {}
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Blank not implemented for {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what's my confusing. I also get started with [example this site](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/4.html). Firstly my *blank.ex* is

```
defprotocol Blank do
  def blank?(data)
end

defimpl Blank, for: Integer do
  def blank?(_), do: false
end

defimpl Blank, for: List do
  def blank?([]), do: true
  def blank?(_), do: false
end
```

and after I compile it `elixirc blank.ex`, it will create these beam files:

```
Elixir.Blank.Integer.beam   Elixir.Blank.List.beam   Elixir.Blank.beam
```

and secondly my *blank.ex* is

```
defprotocol Blank do
  @fallback_to_any true
  def blank?(data)
end

defimpl Blank, for: Any do
  def blank?(_), do: true
end
```

and I compile it again, I got these beam files:

```
Elixir.Blank.Any.beam  Elixir.Blank.Integer.beam Elixir.Blank.List.beam Elixir.Blank.beam
```

It doesn't delete the `Elixir.Blank.Integer.beam Elixir.Blank.List.beam` files,  and when I run in iex:

```
iex(18)> Blank.blank? [] # it uses Elixir.Blank.List.beam
true
iex(19)> Blank.blank? [6] # it uses Elixir.Blank.List.beam
false
iex(20)> Blank.blank? '12' # it uses Elixir.Blank.List.beam
false
iex(22)> Blank.blank? "' " # it uses Elixir.Blank.Any.beam
true
iex(23)> Blank.blank? "elixi" # it uses Elixir.Any.List.beam
true
iex(24)> Blank.blank? {1} # it uses Elixir.Blank.Any.beam
true
iex(25)> Blank.blank? {1, 2} # it uses Elixir.Blank.Any.beam
true
iex(26)> Blank.blank? 2 # it uses Elixir.Blank.Integer.beam
false
```

So this is just because my missing of deleting the older beam files manually.